# How can I join tables using information from different rows?

Tags: sql, join, group-by, google-bigquery

I have two similar tables that I would like to join. See reproducible example below.

WHAT NEEDS TO BE DONE

See comments in code: concatenating the values '2021-01-01'(column: Date), 'hat'(column: content), 'cat'(column: content) and 'A'(column: Tote) in first_table would lead to a unique key that can be joined with the exact same data in second_table. The result would be the first row of the 4 unique events (see desired_result: '#first tote'). In reality the rows would be a few million.

Reproducible example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
`first_table` (
  `Date` string NOT NULL,
  `TotearrivalTimestamp` string  NOT NULL,
  `Tote` string NOT NULL,
  `content` string NOT NULL,
  `location` string NOT NULL,
);
INSERT INTO `first_table` (`Date`, `TotearrivalTimestamp`, `Tote`, `content`, `location`) VALUES
  ('2021-01-01', '13:00','A','hat','1'), #first tote
  ('2021-01-01', '13:00','A','cat','1'), #first tote
  ('2021-01-01', '14:00', 'B', 'toy', '1'),
  ('2021-01-01', '14:00', 'B', 'cat', '1'),
  ('2021-01-01', '15:00', 'A', 'toy', '1'),
  ('2021-01-01', '13:00', 'A', 'toy', '1'),
  ('2021-01-02', '13:00', 'A', 'hat', '1'),
  ('2021-01-02', '13:00', 'A', 'cat', '1');
  
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
`second_table` (
  `Date` string NOT NULL,
  `ToteendingTimestamp` string  NOT NULL,
  `Tote` string NOT NULL,
  `content` string NOT NULL,
  `location` string NOT NULL,
);
INSERT INTO `second_table` (`Date`, `ToteendingTimestamp`, `Tote`, `content`, `location`) VALUES
('2021-01-01', '20:00', 'B', 'cat', '2'),
('2021-01-01', '19:00', 'A', 'cat', '1'), #first tote
('2021-01-01', '19:00', 'A', 'hat', '1'), #first tote
('2021-01-01', '20:00', 'B', 'toy', '2'),
('2021-01-01', '14:00', 'A', 'toy', '1'),
('2021-01-02', '14:00', 'A', 'hat', '1'),
('2021-01-02', '14:00', 'A', 'cat', '1'),
('2021-01-01', '16:00', 'A', 'toy', '1');

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
`desired_result` (
  `Date` string NOT NULL,
  `Tote` string NOT NULL,
  `TotearrivalTimestamp` string  NOT NULL,
  `ToteendingTimestamp` string  NOT NULL,
  `location_first_table` string NOT NULL,
  `location_second_table` string NOT NULL,
 );
INSERT INTO `desired_result` (`Date`, `Tote`, `TotearrivalTimestamp`, `ToteendingTimestamp`, `location_first_table`, `location_second_table`) VALUES

('2021-01-01', 'A', '13:00', '19:00', '1', '1'), #first tote
('2021-01-01', 'B', '14:00', '20:00', '1', '1'),
('2021-01-01', 'A', '15:00', '16:00', '1', '2'),
('2021-01-02', 'A', '13:00', '14:00', '1', '1');


#### this does not give what I want####
select first.date as Date, first.tote, first.totearrivaltimestamp, second.toteendingtimestamp, first.location as location_first_table, second.location as location_second_table
from `first_table` first 
inner join `second_table` second 
on first.tote = second.tote 
and first.content = second.content;
```

Comment: There is no clear description of how the desired output is a function of the input. "based on" & "combined with" tell us nothing & neither does listing operators that might be involved. [mre] Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS Now that you have the input as tablular code (good), you don't need the earlier redundant (& possibly wrong) versions.

Comment: Please act on all of my last comment. Nobody could take what you have written & know what query to write. They can only guess. PS Sentence fragments labeling rows is not "Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean."

Comment: Ok thanks for your support. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the'desired_result' table (mostly) with the SQL below. I believe there exists a few typos with the 'insert into' statements. However, I think this meets the intent.

Query:

```
select  
first_table.date as Date, 
first_table.tote, 
first_table.totearrivaltimestamp, 
second_table.toteendingtimestamp, 
first_table.location as location_first_table, 
second_table.location as location_second_table
from first_table
inner join `second_table` 
on first_table.Date = second_table.Date 
and first_table.tote = second_table.tote
group by first_table.Date, first_table.TotearrivalTimestamp, first_table.tote;
```

result:

```
2021-01-01|A|13:00|19:00|1|1
2021-01-01|B|14:00|20:00|1|2
2021-01-01|A|15:00|19:00|1|1
2021-01-02|A|13:00|14:00|1|1
```

This result assumes your first table dates will always match for totes/timestamps. The group by function then merges duplicate results. The second table information matches the date and tote of the first table and is appended to the line item.

Comment: Code-only answers are strongly discouraged. Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69648283/edit) to explain how/why the code solves the problem. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30130657)

Comment: Thanks for adjusting the other answer, but please consider my own reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

This answer should work. I think your issue might be with some of your quoting of tables....

```
select f.'date'
,f.tote
, f.totearrivaltimestamp
, s.toteendingtimestamp
, f.location as location_first_table
, s.location as location_second_table
from first f
,INNER JOIN "second" s on f.'date' = s.'date'
and f.tote = s.tote 
and f.content = s.content
```

Comment: Syntax error. (Chose the explicit JOIN syntax.)

Comment: no way... will take me 10 times as much time to test this than it took you to build this so please be patient...

Comment: Ah I see that there has been a miscommunication... I want to join all the totes. The final line was just an example! Let me rephrase

Comment: So what I would like is to join the Totes. For example: the first Tote would be joined using '2021-01-01'(Date), 'hat'(content), 'cat'(content) and 'A'(Tote).

Comment: the second one would be  using '2021-01-01'(Date), 'toy'(content), 'cat'(content) and 'B'(Tote)

Comment: also see 'what I would like as a result'

Comment: @jarlh what SQL RDBMS are you using? Not quite sure why you would get that error as this should be ANSI compliant

Comment: @Charles please review the latest edit and upvote if it answers your question

Comment: `... from first f ,(INNER JOIN second ...` should be `... from first f INNER JOIN second ...`.

Comment: BTW, when talking about ANSI SQL compliance, both `date` and `second` are reserved words, i.e. they need to be delimited. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words)

Comment: @jarlh those are the column names, please explain how you would do it? And what RDBMS are you using? I honestly haven't used one that didn't accept that join type and it is a clean visual way to do your joins...

Comment: I can't see any dbms that support  `from first f ,(INNER JOIN second`. Which dbms are _you_ using? "date" and "second" is the way to handle reserved word used as identifiers.

Comment: @jarlh I stand corrected, I code primarily in a proprietary flavor of SQL and had forgotten this was non-standard. So the correct way to do it would be inner join "second"? Can you use [second] as well?

Comment: MS SQL Server, MS-Access, Sybase and perhaps some other support `[second]` as well.

Comment: I adjusted my question so hopefully it is more clear now!

Comment: @Charles I updated my query, let me know if it works